# How correct use where order by having order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I'm currently getting this error from my query in SQL Server:

> The `'table1.nr'` column is invalid in the selection list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and not in the GROUP BY clause.

This is my data from table1

```
nr      artnr   typNr
4747    mob100  3
4747    mob123  4
4842    mob122  1
2051    mob123  5
2051    mob125  5
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT nr
FROM table1
WHERE artnr LIKE '%Mob%'
GROUP BY typNr
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY nr asc;
```

As a result I only want to get

```
nr
4747
```

my query is incorrect, it needs to be covered and typNr is different, in this case it would only be correct for me to get the result nr
4747

Comment: GROUP BY artnr --> GROUP BY nr

Comment: @lptr please look at the question, I did not enter the typNr data code, but it should also be included in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to want :

```
SELECT TOP (1) nr -- remove top clause if you want all rows
FROM table1
WHERE artnr LIKE '%Mob%'
GROUP BY nr
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT typNr) > 1
ORDER BY nr;
```

If you want all columns then you can use `exists` :

```
select t1.*
from tablet1 t1
where exists (select 1 
              from table1 t2 
              where t2.nr = t1.nr and 
                    t2.typNr <> t1.typNr and 
                    t2.artnr like '%mob%'
             );
```

Comment: please look at the question, I did not enter the typNr data code, but it should also be included in the query

Comment: @merci. . . Do not change the question after being answered. Check updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table1 table(nr int, artnr varchar(10), typNr int);

insert into @table1(nr, artnr, typNr)
values
(4747, 'mob100', 3),
(4747, 'mob123', 4),
(4842, 'mob122', 1),
(2051, 'mob123', 5),
(2051, 'mob125', 5) ;

SELECT nr
FROM @table1
WHERE artnr LIKE '%Mob%'
GROUP BY nr
HAVING MIN(typNr) <> MAX(typNr)
ORDER BY nr asc;
```